# how to append dropdown list box

Tags: jquery

```
$("#Grid").click(
        $("#showgrid").load('SomeURL'));
        $.each($('#Grid td:nth-child(4n)'), function() {
         var forthColumn = $(this);
        forthColumn.append("<select><option value='1'>Division 1</option><option value='2'>Division 2</option><option value='3'>Division 3</option></select>");
      });
    };
```

I am trying to append the dropdown list box? this way but I am not seeing the dropdownbox at 4th colum?

is this right?
thanks for all..

Comment: You can write `$(...).each(function() { ... })`

Comment: Please can you expalin me more i will appriciate 

thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do? You'll need to post some of the HTML of your page.

Answer (score 0):

try this way:

```
$("#Grid").bind("click", function(ev) {
  $("#showgrid").load('SomeURL'));
  $(this).find("td:nth-child(4)").each(function(i, el) {
    var forthColumn = $(this);
    forthColumn.append("<select><option value='1'>Division 1</option><option value='2'>Division 2</option><option value='3'>Division 3</option></select>");
  });
});
```